# left join in yii

Tags: yii, criteria

I have 2 tables
**student_job_log**->id,job_id,student_id,created_dt 
**student_info**->id,user_id,first_name,last_name

I have made the relations in model(studentJobLog)

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        'student_info'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'StudentInfo','id','joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN',
                                    'select'=>'first_name, last_name')),


        );
    }
```

I got the error in this
what is the problem.
something is wrong in my relations that i dont know :(

I want the first_name and last_name from student_info plz help me...:(

Comment: hello @jon please give me query(relations) ...I want first_name and last_name from student_info table and created_dt from student_job_log

Comment: I can't do that. If you had a specific problem that was adequately documented, I could help.

Comment: in view file i had written like this echo $data->student_info;exit;nothing is coming output

Comment: Sorry, that's not even close to enough information.

Comment: You mention you received an error, but you didn't say what error it is.  Also if you have `echo $data->student_info;exit;` it is likely that there is no content in `student_info` and so displays nothing. You're showing us partial code and not telling us what the problem is. Nobody can help you without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key must be the one from you current model that is mapped to the StudentInfo

```
    return array(
    'student_info'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'StudentInfo','student_id',),
    );
```

now use it like

```
echo $job->student_info->first_name . ', ' . $job->student_info->last_name;
```